# What does it mean by 'Requires js' when using TailwindCSS?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I am completely new to Vue and Tailwind. I was just looking at https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/elements/headers and saw the `Requires JS` tag. When I copy-paste the code to my project, it gives a blank page. Where do I configure this part to include the JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nvm, I just had to read the documentation. https://tailwindui.com/documentation#using-vue

Comment: I want to use tailwind ready components with simple HTML , where can I get JS file ? I am using components from here "https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/elements/headers". but it wants JS , where to find it ?

Comment: @SwapnilKotkar - I'm trying to use them with Ruby on Rails 7, but lordy the importmaps/JS world is mind-boggling to me. All I want is a dropdown!  Why is this so hard?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find it?

Comment: Same here, where can I find JS file?